# How to read a data,values from a text box on a webpage?

Tags: ios, html, user-data

how to read or fetch the values or data's that a user entered on a webpage in IOS?
i have to get the information that a user entered on an webpage,
any related answers are appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Improve your question, what have you tried, etc etc., Can't help you otherwise...

Comment: can you elaborate your question please ?

Comment: i have to read an data from a page that a user given (ex. in facebook login page if he enters his name and email id i have to read it or store it in my app) IOS

Comment: i have to read a value in a Text Box on a webpage "that the user entered" and thanks for your reply.